# Joomla! Banner Not Tracking Impressions properly

Tags: components, joomla1.5, banner

I'm having a bit of an issue with the default Joomla! Banners component.

I have two banner modules with separate ads on my site home page, both were published at the same time.
One of them is reporting 9241 impressions while the other is only reporting 374.

Even when I re-load the home page, the former updates the impressions count, but the latter doesn't.

Has anyone had any issues/insight with this?

Comment: Side note: I turned off joomla site caching and the banner tracks impressions just fine now. Can anyone think of a reason this ONE (of may) banner modules is affected this way because of caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well then. It seems I didn't realize modules modules had individual cache settings. Looks like one banner module had caching set to 'Use Global'. I changed it to 'No Caching' and it's fine now.
Lesson learned!